# Can you declare a List of a class within another class?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a simple order sheet that has products, customers, order lines, and an order sheet. Currently, I am just hardcoding in products and customers for simple testing purposes. With the order sheet, I want to have a List of the order line items (contains quantity and price from products, and a few other bits of information) in the order class. When I create the order in the program, it's not creating the List of order line items that I have in the constructor. I have tried to .Add within the constructor which didn't work as well in the program, in the program it states it does not contain the definition Add.

When I try to access .test it shows as NULL.

```
namespace ObjectsCSharpe.Library
class Order
{
    public Order()
    {
        var testLine = new List<OrderLineItems>();
    }
    public List<OrderLineItems> testLine { get; set; }
}

 class OrderLineItems
 {
    public OrderLineItems()
    {
        this.orderID = 0;
        this.lineNumber = 0;
        this.product = new Product();
        this.quantity = 0;
        this.test = "OLI";
        this.lineTotal = 0.00;
    }
    public int orderID { get; set; }
    public int lineNumber { get; set; }
    public Product product { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string test { get; set; }
    public double lineTotal { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Order orderSheet = new Order();
        OrderLineItems temp456 = new OrderLineItems();
        orderSheet.testLine.Add(temp456);
        string abc = orderSheet.testLine[0].test;
        Console.WriteLine(abc);
    }
}
```

Comment: Remove `~Order()` and `~OrderLineItems` ... there's no reason to have finalizers in these classes.

Comment: I didn't understand your question?Could you explain it more?

Comment: There seems to be a lot of code missing. When I copy and paste your code I get a lot of errors. None of which is the error you're saying you get.

Comment: We need a [mcve] to help you solve this.

Comment: Certainly, this might help it make more sense. Eventually, I will be connecting this to a database where each class (Product, customer, order line and order) will be a table. When I create the Order in the program I want it to make a List of Order Line Items that I can add to in the program.

Comment: @Jimi both of those names are what I was using to try and figure out what my issue was. I know the names are not the correct naming method, but this is my trial and error code that I have been using.

Comment: can you post the whole code, and also the highlight the portion where you are facing the issue

Comment: No lets stop here! this question is messy. you need to remove all the code that is working, and face one problem at a time, the order line items.... create a small example with only order and oder line items in a console app , and show us the problem. at its current rate this question will take 100 more comments to understand the problem. I'm voting to close until you do

Comment: @MichaelRandall I think the question is pretty clear, I want to make a List of a class within another class and be able to add to that list from the program. I can edit the question to contain the " be able to add to that list from the program" . Just trying to understand how to write it in the constructor and use it in the program.

Comment: @Celtic89 It is absolutely not clear, people will skip past this wall of text code presentation. Reduce the amount of code.

Comment: @TanveerBadar I removed all of the added code that was requested in a previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start with this excerpt:

```
public Order()
{
    var testLine = new List<OrderLineItems>();
}
```

This is the constructor for the `Order` type. In this code, the `var` keyword means you are **declaring a new variable**, where the scope of the variable is **limited to that method**. The type also contains this:

```
public List<OrderLineItems> testLine { get; set; }
```

So there is a separate `testLine` variable in the type. But, in the constructor, the use of `var` means this other variable was not touched.

Later on we have this code:

```
orderSheet.testLine.Add(temp456);
```

Unfortunately, because of the earlier mistake, *`orderSheet.testLine` is still `null`*, and you can't call a method on a `null` reference.

You can fix this as easily as removing `var` from the constructor:

```
public Order()
{
    testLine = new List<OrderLineItems>();
}
```

or, even better, remove the entire constructor from the type completely. Initialize the list property where it is declared and make it get-only:

```
public class Order   
{   
    public List<OrderLineItems> testLine {get;} = new List<OrderLineItems>();
}
```

*(Note: You can still add items to get-only List property.)*

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make public keyword while creating all your class.

```
public class Order{
    //Add Your class declaration...
}
```